# proxy.invoke not working outside connection start in react native signalr

Tags: react-native, signalr

I am developing a `react-native` mobile app with an `asp.net` server which run a `signalr` server.
Following is my code inside `componentDidMount`. Here, connection to server is made successfully, and server methods inside `.start().done()` is executed successfully on server.

```
const connection = signalr.hubConnection(url);
//connection.logging = true;
proxy = connection.createHubProxy("mobileStockTickerHub");
proxy.on("msgreceived", (msg) => {
  //Alert.alert("Hi", "Message:" + msg);
  this.setState({ randomdata: msg });
  //console.log(this.state.randomdata);
});

// attempt connection, and handle errors
connection
  .start()
  .done(() => {
    console.log("Now connected, connection ID=" + connection.id);

    proxy
      .invoke("setUserName", "Hemal")
      .done((directResponse) => {
        console.log("direct-response-from-server", directResponse);
      })
      .fail(() => {
        console.warn(
          "Something went wrong when calling server, it might not be up and running?"
        );
      });
    proxy.invoke("subscribeToSymbols", "123");//THIS METHOD I NEED TO CALL FROM SOMEWHERE ELSE IN THE PAGE, NOT HERE IMMEDIATELY AFTER CONNECTION MADE
  })
  .fail(() => {
    console.log("Failed");
  });

//connection-handling
connection.connectionSlow(() => {
  console.log(
    "We are currently experiencing difficulties with the connection."
  );
});

connection.error((error) => {
  const errorMessage = error.message;
  let detailedError = "";
  if (error.source && error.source._response) {
    detailedError = error.source._response;
  }
  if (
    detailedError ===
    "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
  ) {
    console.log(
      "When using react-native-signalr on ios with http remember to enable http in App Transport Security https://github.com/olofd/react-native-signalr/issues/14"
    );
  }
  console.debug("SignalR error: " + errorMessage, detailedError);
});
```

The method to invoke inside connection.start().done() works,this one `proxy.invoke("subscribeToSymbols", "123")`, but what if I want to execute some methods on server, not after connection made immediate, but later when some button clicks.

When doing this invoke call from a button click, following error displayed.

```
Error: SignalR: Connection has not been fully initialized. Use .start().done() or .start().fail() to run logic after the connection has started.
```

I am using this npm package of signalr for react native, `https://github.com/olofd/react-native-signalr`

Answer (score 0):

You can move the invoke outside of the connection.start().done() but you will want to disable the button until after the connection has been made. You could enable the button after connection is successful.

As far as the button goes, just call the on click event for that button and place your invoke within that event trigger.

A jQuery example -

```
$("#myButton").on("click", function (e) { 
    proxy = connection.createHubProxy("mobileStockTickerHub");
    proxy.invoke("subscribeToSymbols", "123")
}
```

Comment: I tried that with react-native button, but error displayed as shown, when clicked on button.

Comment: Not sure how you implemented that button. But you may need to include your proxy declaration. I will update the code above.

Comment: It's a react-native `TouchableOpacity` with `onPress` event, firing a function.

Comment: @Hemal Can you post the code you tried to see if there is an issue there? Maybe someone more familiar with React can spot something.